# Cannot load html from a different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, sails.js

I have the following code:

```
<script>
   var load = function load_home(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="/linker/templates/button.html" ></object>';
   }
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

But it does not load anything, also console does not display any errors.
This is inside a sails.js app

Comment: Firstly your syntax creating the function is incorrect, secondly you never actually call the function to execute it.

Comment: how do I run it? I tried window.onload=.. but it did not work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I couldn't see syntax incorrect, can you please notice to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not calling load function, call it when your window loads,

```
<script>
   var load = function load_home(){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="/linker/templates/button.html" ></object>';
   }
   window.onload=function(){
      load();
  }
</script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: it works! thanks. But now chrome sais it needs a pluging to display it